# d3.js (d.geometry.coordinates) issue when placing labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label

I'm trying to place labels using the larskotthoff block page http://bl.ocks.org/larskotthoff/11406992

The issue I'm having is where the labels translate is worked out on the line.

```
.attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates[0][0][0]) + ")";
     })
```

So in his guide he is not doing d.geometry.coordinates[0][0][0] but just d.geometry.coordinates. This works for him because he is not working out the labels for multi-polygons because when I tried without the [0][0][0]

So my labels are not where they should be as you can see in the following image.

[image: Map photo]

Although I've managed to get the labels drawing the structure of my feature (in this case d) is different and not a single array of coordinates. It is a 3 dimension array. So for this reason the placement (translate) is happening based on the first element [0][0][0] of each dimension. How do I overcome this? I want it to work out its placement from the whole set of polygons. Does d3 make something available for this?

UPDATE: Solution (thanks to Lars)

```
                          .data(json.features)
                      .enter().append("text")
                      .attr("class", "place-label")
                      .attr("transform", function (d) {
                          console.log("test");
                          return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")";
                      })
                      .attr("x", function (d) {
                          return path.centroid(d)[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6;
                      })
                      .attr("dy", ".35em")
                      .style("text-anchor", function (d) {
                          return path.centroid(d)[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end";
                      })
```

Comment: Use `path.centroid()` as in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897534/add-names-of-the-states-to-a-map-in-d3-js).

Comment: Thanks - that sorts it out. I'm going to edit my question to include my exagt code so you get a fuller picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lars Kotthoff confirms in comment. To get the centre location from a node/feature you can use path.centroid as described in the d3 documentation below.

[Path.centroid](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#path_centroid)