# Parsing through a GeoJson in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am having difficulty saving the names in a variable or something, found in features.properties.ADMIN as to call them for a tooltip. I wish to save them where it would simply call d.country or something for my tooltip.

```js
d3.json('countries.geojson', function(drawMaps) {
 
 var features = drawMaps.features
 var data2;
 data2 = drawMaps.parse(function(d) { 
   
  return {
   country: d.features.properties.ADMIN
  };
 });
  console.log(drawMaps.features[1].properties.ADMIN);
  console.log(features[2].properties.ADMIN);
});
```

**Edit 1.**

d3.json('countries.geojson', function(drawMaps2) {

```
for (var j = 0; j < drawMaps2.features.length; j++)  {
    var jsonCountry = drawMaps2.features[j].properties.ADMIN;
    console.log(jsonCountry);
 break;
 }
console.log(jsonCountry);
console.log(drawMaps2.features[3].properties.ADMIN);

});
```

Comment: can you post an example of your countries.geojson? are you trying to extract the country names from the data?

Comment: `code`  "features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ADMIN": "Aruba", "ISO_A3": "ABW" }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ -69.99... `code`

Comment: following that is just the co-ordinates

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53212165/correctly-accessing-assigned-json-coordinates-for-d3-map-labels/53213858#53213858

Comment: I have used the basis of that, so i have gotten to in the edit. However in the variable only one entry is been stored. So it is not looping through to my understanding.

Comment: could you make functional example on jsfiddle.net?