# How to get width and other positioning values of map using d3 js

Tags: jquery, d3.js

I'm creating map of USA where I need to display the name of every state by pointing the mid point of that state with a line. So my approach for this was , I have added ID  attribute to each state dynamically during the creation of map and then I have tried using jquery to get left and width of those states but the problem is by the time this jquery call is happening the map is not being rendered so this jquery calls are returning nulls. Can someone please help me with this with some example code.
PS:I'm using g albersusa projection.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You can the center of each path (state) to put a label there?  See [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths#path_centroid).  And also this [quesiton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897534/add-names-of-the-states-to-a-map-in-d3-js).