# Rotate the text placed in map d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Using this I was able to add names to the map: [Add names of the states to a map in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897534/add-names-of-the-states-to-a-map-in-d3-js/13899232#13899232)

Now, how do I rotate those text as it is overlapping with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for the solution.

Adding this solved it. It produces composition matrix.

```
.attr('transform', function(d) {
    return 'translate('+path.centroid(d)[0]+','+path.centroid(d)[1]+') rotate(-45);
})
```

Here is the updated code:

```
function draw(){

  d3.json("readme.json", function(json) {
    g.selectAll("path")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
    .on("click", click);

    g.selectAll("text")
    .data(json.features)
    .enter()
    .append("svg:text")
    .text(function(d){
        return d.properties.name;
    })
    // .attr("x", function(d){
    //     return path.centroid(d)[0];
    // })
    // .attr("y", function(d){
    //     return  path.centroid(d)[1];
    // })
    .attr("text-anchor","middle")
    .attr('font-size','6pt')

    // added
    .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate('+path.centroid(d)[0]+','+path.centroid(d)[1]+') rotate(-45);
    })

  });
}
```