# How to put the state name into the Geo chart/D3.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, d3.js, svg, geo

I met a problem that I want to put the state name on my geo chart. I tried to use others' method, but they cannot well-matched with my chart. Could you please let me know what's wrong with my code and how to improve it.Thank you in advance!

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylemap.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "chart"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script src="mainmap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mainmap.js:

```
//weight and height
var chart_height = 600;
var chart_width = 800;

var color = d3.scaleQuantize().range([  'rgb(255,245,240)','rgb(254,224,210)','rgb(252,187,161)',
                                        'rgb(252,146,114)','rgb(251,106,74)','rgb(239,59,44)',
                                        'rgb(203,24,29)','rgb(165,15,21)','rgb(103,0,13)']);

//Projection

var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa()
                    .scale([chart_width])
                    .translate([chart_width / 2, chart_height / 2 ]);
                    // .translate([0, 100]);

var path = d3.geoPath(projection);
            // .projection(projection);


//create svg
var svg = d3.select('#chart')
            .append("svg")
            .attr('width', chart_width)
            .attr('height', chart_height);

// svg.append("rect")
// .attr("class", "background")
// .attr("width", width)
// .attr("height", height);


var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + chart_width / 2 + "," + chart_height / 2 + ")")
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", "states");

//Data
d3.json('zombie-attacks.json').then(function(zombie_data){
    color.domain([
        d3.min(zombie_data, function(d){
            return d.num;
        }),
        d3.max(zombie_data, function(d){
            return d.num;
        })
    ]);
d3.json('us.json').then(function(us_data){
    us_data.features.forEach(function(us_e, us_i){
        zombie_data.forEach(function(z_e,z_i){
            if(us_e.properties.name !== z_e.state){
                return null;
            }
            us_data.features[us_i].properties.num = parseFloat(z_e.num)
        });
    });
    // console.log(us_data)
    svg.selectAll('path')
        .data(us_data.features)
        .enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('d',path)
        .attr('fill', function(d){
            var num = d.properties.num;
            return num ? color(num) : '#ddd';
        })

        .text(function(d){
            return d.properties.name;
        })
        .attr('stroke', '#fff')
        .attr('stroke-width',1)
        .attr("class", "country-label")
        .append("text")
        // .attr("transform", function(d) { console.log("d", d); return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
        // .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })
        .attr("dy", function (d) {
            return "0.35em";
        })
        .style('fill', 'black');
    g.selectAll("text")
     .data(us_data.features)
     .enter()
     .append("text")
     .text(function(d){
         return d.properties.name;
     })
     .attr("x", function(d){
         return path.centroid(d)[0];
     })
     .attr("y", function(d){
         return  path.centroid(d)[1];
     })
     .attr("text-anchor","middle")
     .attr('font-size','6pt')
     .style('fill', 'green');
     })
})
```

// [Add names of the states to a map in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897534/add-names-of-the-states-to-a-map-in-d3-js)

[image: screenshot of wrong -matched]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending text and path to different parents: `svg` and `g`. This is an issue because:

```
var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + chart_width / 2 + "," + chart_height / 2 + ")")
```

Your `g`, with the text has a transform that the `svg` doesn't. Which is why your text is pushed width/2, height/2 further than the projected paths. Just use `svg.selectAll` for the text.

The projection already has a translate applied to it, you can either apply the translation to the parent or to the projection, but shouldn't use both.

Comment: Hi Andrew: Thanks very much for your comments! I revised the text function for g and use svg.selectAll("text") to try to add the state's name. But the text are still not shown in the map? I am wondering is that becasue the color is not transparent? Or is there any other issues? Thanks again for your time!

Comment: There may be an issue with appending text to the paths - you're reselecting the paths's child text elements. You could skip appending the child text to the paths (which shouldn't render anyways, it looks like a remnant of earlier revisions), or try `svg.selectAll(null)` to enter everything when appending the text. If it is neither of those, then it could be the text is rendering in weird spots, inspecting the DOM might show where they are hiding.

Comment: Thanks ! Andrew! Fixed! I just tried svg.selectAll(null) and solved!