# Add title text to the center of path in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, choropleth

I'm creating an svg path and I need to set the `Title` at center of path. I've tried many example but failed.

Please check the code snippet. How do I add a each `Title` at it's center position?

**Note**: I just use `path`, not coordinates!

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const h = 300;
  const w = 300;

  const svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w);

  svg
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(map)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", (m) => m.path)
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr('fill','#fff')

  svg
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(map)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("fill", "#fff")
    .text((m) =>m.title)
    .attr("x", (m) => m.id)
    .attr("y", (m) => m.id)
    .attr("transform", (m) => "translate(" + m.id + "," + m.id + ")");
});

const map=[ {
    id: 0,
    title: "Title 1",
    path: "M 45.25 34.96 l -0.97 -3.35 l -0.97 -2.39 l 2.43 -3.35 l 1.94 -4.31 l 1.94 -5.74 l 3.89 -5.74 l 0.97 6.22 l 0.49 3.35 l 3.89 3.83 l 3.89 -0.96 l 0.97 3.35 l 3.89 0.96 l 0.49 2.87 l 3.89 1.44 l 0.49 1.91 L 76.36 34 l 2.43 -2.87 l 1.46 3.83 l 1.94 2.39 l 2.92 1.91 l 0.97 1.91 l 2.43 -0.96 l 1.46 1.44 l -1.46 3.35 l 1.46 1.44 l 1.94 1.44 v 0.96 l 3.89 -0.48 v 1.91 l 0.97 1.91 v 2.39 l 2.43 1.91 l -0.49 4.31 l 1.94 3.35 l 2.43 3.35 l -0.97 3.35 v 4.79 v 4.31 l -1.46 3.83 l 0.97 4.79 l -2.43 3.35 l -3.4 4.79 l -3.89 -0.96 l -5.35 -0.48 l -1.94 -3.83 l -2.43 -1.91 l 2.92 -5.26 l -1.94 -3.83 l -2.43 -2.87 l -3.89 -1.44 l -1.94 -1.91 l -1.46 -2.87 l -2.43 0.96 c 0 0 -0.61 -0.48 -1.94 -0.96 s -3.4 -0.96 -3.4 -0.96 l -2.43 -0.96 l -2.43 1.91 l -3.89 -0.96 l -3.4 -1.44 l -2.92 1.91 l -0.49 2.39 c 0 0 -1.58 -0.24 -3.4 -0.96 c -1.82 -0.72 -3.89 -1.91 -3.89 -1.91 l -0.97 -1.44 l 3.4 -1.91 l 1.94 -2.39 l -1.46 -2.87 v -6.7 l 5.35 -0.48 l 1.94 -1.91 l 1.94 -2.87 l 4.37 -1.44 l 0.97 -3.35 l 2.43 3.83 l 2.43 -1.44 l 1.94 -3.35 l -1.94 -2.39 l -1.94 -2.87 v -3.35 l -3.4 -2.87 l -4.37 0.96 l -2.43 -3.83 l -2.43 1.91 l -2.92 -0.48 L 45.25 34.96 Z",
  },{
id: 1,
title: "Ttitle 2",
path: "M 19.49 126.38 l -2.43 -4.31 l -2.92 -3.83 l 1.94 -4.31 l -4.86 -0.96 l 1.46 -7.66 l 3.4 -2.39 l -0.49 -2.87 l 1.94 -3.83 l 5.83 -3.83 l 1.94 -5.26 l -4.37 -2.39 l 2.43 -4.31 l 0.97 -4.31 l 5.35 -1.91 v -4.79 l 7.29 0.96 l 5.35 -1.44 l 7.29 4.79 l 1.46 -3.83 l 4.96 -1.03 l 4.27 1.51 l 3.89 -0.48 l 9.72 2.39 l 3.89 4.31 l 3.4 1.44 l 4.86 5.74 l -3.4 4.79 l 0.97 3.35 l -2.43 2.39 l -0.97 3.83 h -3.4 l -2.43 -3.83 l -1.46 2.87 h -2.92 l -1.46 5.27 l 1.94 1.91 l -2.43 0.48 l -2.92 4.79 l -0.97 2.87 l -1.46 2.87 l 1.94 2.39 l -2.92 0.48 h -1.94 v -2.39 l -6.32 0.48 v 3.83 h -2.43 l -0.49 4.79 l 2.92 1.44 l -1.94 1.91 v 4.31 l 2.43 1.44 l 2.92 2.39 l -0.49 3.35 l -3.4 0.48 l -2.92 -2.87 l -2.43 -1.44 v -1.92 l -3.4 -3.35 h -2.92 l -0.97 -3.35 l -5.35 -2.87 l 0.49 -2.39 l -0.49 -1.44 l -4.37 1.44 l -2.92 2.39 l -2.43 -2.87 L 19.49 126.38 Z",
  }]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897534/add-names-of-the-states-to-a-map-in-d3-js) link is useful for your problem.

Comment: No.. it returns diff error. I don't use coordinates. I just append `path`, maybe that's why. By the way, Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have the path data you can consider getting the [bounding box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) of the `path`s and using the centre point of this box.

With irregularly shaped geographical regions this will differ from the location of the `centroid`, but the label will be more often than not appear centered 'enough'.

See the edits below:

- The path is classed (as `region`) so we can select in the next step
- Use d3 [`each`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_each) over the selection of the regions and use `getBBox`
- Find the centre of the bbox and use that to position the label
- Use a [`text-anchor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) of `middle`

Working example:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const h = 300;
  const w = 300;

  const svg = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("height", h)
    .attr("width", w);

  svg
    .selectAll(".region") // <-- select the class
    .data(map)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "region") // <-- add the class
    .attr("d", (m) => m.path)
    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
    .attr("stroke", "#000")
    .attr('fill','#fff')

  svg
    .selectAll(".region") // <-- now we can select the paths and get the bbox
    .each((d, i, nodes) => {
      const bbox = d3.select(nodes[i]).node().getBBox();
      const centreX = bbox.x + (bbox.width / 2); // <-- get x centre 
      const centreY = bbox.y + (bbox.height / 2); // <-- get y centre
      svg 
        .append("text") // <-- now add the text element
        .text(d.title)
        .attr("x", centreX)
        .attr("y", centreY)
        .attr("fill", "#0804ee")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    });
    
    
    
});

const map=[ {
    id: 0,
    title: "Title 1",
    path: "M 45.25 34.96 l -0.97 -3.35 l -0.97 -2.39 l 2.43 -3.35 l 1.94 -4.31 l 1.94 -5.74 l 3.89 -5.74 l 0.97 6.22 l 0.49 3.35 l 3.89 3.83 l 3.89 -0.96 l 0.97 3.35 l 3.89 0.96 l 0.49 2.87 l 3.89 1.44 l 0.49 1.91 L 76.36 34 l 2.43 -2.87 l 1.46 3.83 l 1.94 2.39 l 2.92 1.91 l 0.97 1.91 l 2.43 -0.96 l 1.46 1.44 l -1.46 3.35 l 1.46 1.44 l 1.94 1.44 v 0.96 l 3.89 -0.48 v 1.91 l 0.97 1.91 v 2.39 l 2.43 1.91 l -0.49 4.31 l 1.94 3.35 l 2.43 3.35 l -0.97 3.35 v 4.79 v 4.31 l -1.46 3.83 l 0.97 4.79 l -2.43 3.35 l -3.4 4.79 l -3.89 -0.96 l -5.35 -0.48 l -1.94 -3.83 l -2.43 -1.91 l 2.92 -5.26 l -1.94 -3.83 l -2.43 -2.87 l -3.89 -1.44 l -1.94 -1.91 l -1.46 -2.87 l -2.43 0.96 c 0 0 -0.61 -0.48 -1.94 -0.96 s -3.4 -0.96 -3.4 -0.96 l -2.43 -0.96 l -2.43 1.91 l -3.89 -0.96 l -3.4 -1.44 l -2.92 1.91 l -0.49 2.39 c 0 0 -1.58 -0.24 -3.4 -0.96 c -1.82 -0.72 -3.89 -1.91 -3.89 -1.91 l -0.97 -1.44 l 3.4 -1.91 l 1.94 -2.39 l -1.46 -2.87 v -6.7 l 5.35 -0.48 l 1.94 -1.91 l 1.94 -2.87 l 4.37 -1.44 l 0.97 -3.35 l 2.43 3.83 l 2.43 -1.44 l 1.94 -3.35 l -1.94 -2.39 l -1.94 -2.87 v -3.35 l -3.4 -2.87 l -4.37 0.96 l -2.43 -3.83 l -2.43 1.91 l -2.92 -0.48 L 45.25 34.96 Z",
  },{
id: 1,
title: "Ttitle 2",
path: "M 19.49 126.38 l -2.43 -4.31 l -2.92 -3.83 l 1.94 -4.31 l -4.86 -0.96 l 1.46 -7.66 l 3.4 -2.39 l -0.49 -2.87 l 1.94 -3.83 l 5.83 -3.83 l 1.94 -5.26 l -4.37 -2.39 l 2.43 -4.31 l 0.97 -4.31 l 5.35 -1.91 v -4.79 l 7.29 0.96 l 5.35 -1.44 l 7.29 4.79 l 1.46 -3.83 l 4.96 -1.03 l 4.27 1.51 l 3.89 -0.48 l 9.72 2.39 l 3.89 4.31 l 3.4 1.44 l 4.86 5.74 l -3.4 4.79 l 0.97 3.35 l -2.43 2.39 l -0.97 3.83 h -3.4 l -2.43 -3.83 l -1.46 2.87 h -2.92 l -1.46 5.27 l 1.94 1.91 l -2.43 0.48 l -2.92 4.79 l -0.97 2.87 l -1.46 2.87 l 1.94 2.39 l -2.92 0.48 h -1.94 v -2.39 l -6.32 0.48 v 3.83 h -2.43 l -0.49 4.79 l 2.92 1.44 l -1.94 1.91 v 4.31 l 2.43 1.44 l 2.92 2.39 l -0.49 3.35 l -3.4 0.48 l -2.92 -2.87 l -2.43 -1.44 v -1.92 l -3.4 -3.35 h -2.92 l -0.97 -3.35 l -5.35 -2.87 l 0.49 -2.39 l -0.49 -1.44 l -4.37 1.44 l -2.92 2.39 l -2.43 -2.87 L 19.49 126.38 Z",
  }]
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/scss/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mackenxie, I need one more help, look in your solution. The `Title 1 & 2` has been overflow out of the path. So how to increase the `width` of these element.

Comment: @mrhrifat sorry, not sure what you mean ? The label overlaps with the border of the map region - this will happen for various combinations of label and region. There's a possibility to use the largest rectangle contained within the path and then figure out the font size that works best to have the label fully contained within that rectangle but it's too much for an edit to my answer. See here for example: https://www.drdobbs.com/database/the-maximal-rectangle-problem/184410529?pgno=1. Go ahead and ask another question if that's the approach you want to pursue.